# Mule default catch exception and stopping a flow

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio

I created a default catch exception in Mule to be executed whenever an error is thrown in my flow. However, it seems that once the end of the exception is reached (I run a couple components in it), the execution of the flow resumes from that point, which is expectable since the error was caught. I'd like, however, to have the execution of the flow completely stop if the catch exception was triggered. The only way I found was to add an error filter to the main flow, but this seems like a temporary solution, since I would have to add an error filter after each element of the flow to have the intended result.

Comment: Can you post some config? If you've caught the exception, that flow should stop. It could be the processing strategy if your using flow-ref's etc.

Comment: My flow contains flow refs, as well as a foreach that contains flowrefs. Because my endpoint is an HTTP (full loop, request and response), the default processing policy appears to be synchronous.

Comment: What I see however when running my flow is that the execution of the main flow continues until the end, after the catch (which happens in a flow ref)

Comment: Yes the calling/parent flow will continue because exceptions are caught in the private flow. Thats one of the main reasons behind private-flows. If you want the parent flow to stop, it would be better to use a sub-flow or put the exception strategy in the parent flow instead.

Answer (score 1):

in your exception strategy add a scripting component to stop the flow:

```
 <scripting:component doc:name="Script">
        <scripting:script engine="groovy"><![CDATA[
            muleContext.getRegistry().get('<FLOW_NAME>').stop()
        ]]></scripting:script>
    </scripting:component>
```